# I want to read the audio data from Mac or any other third party device(i.e. Amplifi etc) via USB cable on iOS device

Tags: ios, core-audio, xcode7

I am able to read the microphone data with remote I/O framework but i want to read digital audio data via USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Get a camera connection kit allowing you to connect USB to your iOS Device

Probe the device to see how many actual input channels are available after you connect it:

```
NSInteger _inputADChannels;
NSError* err1;
NSInteger maxChannels = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]maximumInputNumberOfChannels];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels:maxChannels error:&err1];
_inputADChannels = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] inputNumberOfChannels];
NSLog(@"A/D inputchannels %li",(long)_inputADChannels);
```

Reading from the hardware bus (bus 1) on the remote IO will read from your usb input.